# Django i18n url is not working with en-us sublanguage

Tags: django, internationalization, django-urls

My django app's using i18n_patterns in urls.py and when I go to my app with the url like:

myapp.com/en/

myapp.com/de/

myapp.com/en-gb/

The urls above works fine but the url **myapp.com/en-us/** gave me an 404 error.

I think the problem is that (https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/conf/global_settings.py) Django's default LANGUAGE_CODE is 'en-us' but there is no 'en-us' in the default LANGUAGES setting. That's why I got 404 page.

Should I just change the LANGUAGE_CODE to 'en' or add 'en-us' to the LANGUAGES setting?

Is the default 'en-us' LANGUAGE_CDE setting useless when using with i18n URL?

Answer (score 4):

You should add `en-us` to LANGUAGES like this:

```
LANGUAGES += (
    ('en-us', ugettext('English-American')),
)
```

Although I think it would be the same as simple `en - English`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually the reverse function generates url like `/en-us/api/` so my test cases returned 404 result with the url. I have to either convert the url after reverse or apply the above solution.

Comment: I ended up updating `settings.py` from `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'`to `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'`.